# Expand pixel 'obects' only on downhill side Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a few thousand pixel patches/objects stored in a single mask image. Each patch represents the location of a snow algal bloom. **I want to "grow" the patches downhill in the direction of the blue arrows** using image-based methods. Each patch is at a different elevation (depending on aspect, latitude etc).

[image]

I tried using a cumulative cost function with the dem in hopes that it would expand downhill, but the function seems to be work relative to each pixel, so it just expands outwards like so:
[image]

Perhaps there is a way using object-based methods to calculate the minimum elevation per patch, and then somehow mask each buffer per-patch using that elevation mask?

```
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');
var dem = ee.Image("MERIT/DEM/v1_0_3");
Map.addLayer(dem,{min:1000, max:2000, palette:palettes.matplotlib.viridis[7]}, "elevation")

var patches = ee.Image("projects/ee-caseyengstrom/assets/globalSnowAlgae/3_algaeMaps/medianElvAlgaeMask").neq(2).selfMask()
Map.addLayer(patches,{palette:['red']}, 'elv algae mask')
Map.centerObject(denali, 9)


// try cumulative cost function ---------------

var cumulativeCost = dem
  .cumulativeCost({
    source: patches,
    maxDistance: 1000, // add up to 1 km
    geodeticDistance: false
  })
  // .aside(Map.addLayer, {min:1e5, max:1e6}, "cumulative cost function")


// assign unique ID to each object ------------------

var objectId = patches.connectedComponents({
  connectedness: ee.Kernel.plus(1),
  maxSize: 1024
}).aside(Map.addLayer)

// find the minimum elevation per object?
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7e1082d12f1f770bf161699233564280

Answer (score 0):

I used `reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.min())` to find the minimum elevation of each patch, and then buffered the min elevation points using `focalMin`.

```
// assign unique ID to each object
var objectId = patches.rename('algae_mask')
  .connectedComponents({
    connectedness: ee.Kernel.plus(1),
    maxSize: 1024
  })//.aside(Map.addLayer)

// find the minimum elevation per object
var minElv = objectId
  .addBands(dem)
  .reduceConnectedComponents({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    labelBand: 'labels'//,
    // maxSize:
  }).select('dem').rename('min_elv')

// mask dem by min elev
var minMask = dem.eq(minElv.select('min_elv')).selfMask()
// Map.addLayer(minMask)

// buffer min points
var buff = minMask.focalMin({radius:3000, units:'meters'})
  .updateMask(glacierMask)
  .aside(Map.addLayer)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4492caa910ce714ca4f7589b14402ae9
[image]